# How to handle Itemclick listener recyclerview

Tags: android, click, android-recyclerview

I am using Recyclerview for menu category and I want to handle item click listener to start other activity with put extra, please any one have experience about this answer my question.

the bellow are my code java. if posible I want to put click listener in ProductCategory.class because I want to use this module(ProductServiceCategoryContractor, ProductServiceCategoryAdapter) many time.

ProductServiceCategoryContractor.java (properties)

```
public class ProductServiceCategoryContractor {
    private int img;

    public ProductServiceCategoryContractor(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    private String title;

    public ProductServiceCategoryContractor(int img, String title) {
        this.img = img;
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(int img) {
        this.img = img;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

ProductServiceCategoryAdapter.java

```
public class ProductServiceCategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductServiceCategoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ProductServiceCategoryContractor> albumList;
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout layout;
        public ImageView img;
        public TextView title;
        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
            layout=(LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }
    }
    public ProductServiceCategoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<ProductServiceCategoryContractor> albumList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.albumList = albumList;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.product_menu_model, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductServiceCategoryContractor album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getTitle());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getImg()).into(holder.img);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return albumList.size();
    }
}
```

ProductCategory.java

```
public class ProductCategory extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ProductServiceCategoryAdapter adapter;
    private List<ProductServiceCategoryContractor> albumList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_category);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.product_category);
        albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ProductServiceCategoryAdapter(this, albumList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        prepareAlbums();
    }
    private void prepareAlbums() {
        int[] covers = new int[]{
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher
        };
        ProductServiceCategoryContractor pl_list = new ProductServiceCategoryContractor(covers[0], "Phone Spare parts & Accessory");
        albumList.add(pl_list);
        pl_list = new ProductServiceCategoryContractor(covers[0], "Computer Networking");
        albumList.add(pl_list);
        pl_list = new ProductServiceCategoryContractor("Clothing Accessory");
        albumList.add(pl_list);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp(){
        finish();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To handle click in recyclerview, use **RecyclerItemClickListener** and use **recyclerview1.addOnItemTouchListener(lisenter)**.

Answer (score 2):

Implement ViewHolder with View.OnClickListener, override OnClick method and create an interface, now you can use onclick method while creating ViewHolder.
Here is simple exmple ...

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        public IMyViewHolderClicks mListener;


        public ViewHolder(View v, IMyViewHolderClicks listener) {

            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.myOnClick(v, getLayoutPosition());
        }


        public static interface IMyViewHolderClicks {
            public void myOnClick(View caller, int position);
        }
    }

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        //..............
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                         int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_list_item, parent, false);

        MyCustomAdapter.ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, new PostsAdapter.ViewHolder.IMyViewHolderClicks() {
            @Override
            public void myOnClick(View caller, int position) {

                //Add your onclick event here
            }
        });

        return vh;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        //..........
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you really need `getLayoutPosition()` as position. In most cases you need `getAdapterPosition()`, related to the data.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to implement `OnClickListener` inside `RecyclerView` adapter.

1. You can implement click listener inside `onBindViewHolder()` method like below

   ```
   holder.buttoncalling.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      // perform click operation
   });
   ```
2. You can also implement it inside you `ItemHolder` like this

   ```
   buttoncalling.setOnClickListener( new  View.OnClickListener(){
      // perform click operation    
   });
   ```

and use `getAdapterPosition()` whenever you need item clicked position as recommended in [official docs.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getAdapterPosition())

3. You can also make **interface callbacks** to your Activity and pass position along with it for refrence.

Answer (score 0):

Put your onClickListener in onBindViewHolder..

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ProductServiceCategoryContractor album = albumList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(album.getTitle());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getImg()).into(holder.img);

        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, OtherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("extra", "message");
                mContext.startActivity(intent); 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You do not need set onClickListener on every onBind event, use instead onCreateViewHolder, as pointed @dhiraj-sharma